# Iterating through list of multiple dictionary to show key only once and value in columns

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

there I have been trying to show list of dictionaries in Jinja template. I need to show key only once as both dictionary have same key. However, value needs to be shown in different column in same rows as key. Problem is its keep showing key and value in same column.

Bellow is my code.

```
            {%for r in result%}
            {%for keyCategory, valueCategory in r.items()%}
            <div class="jumbotron p-3" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label class=" text-right">{{keyCategory}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-left" id="idInput{{ keyCategory }}"
                            value="{{ valueCategory }}">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            {%endfor%}
            {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Please clarify using a sample of what kind of data is inside the list.

Comment: Key = Categories, Value = Amount (In a list of multiple dictionary with same key,  value with different amount, so I would like to show in a way that left hand side categories and on right hand side in one column first dictionary value, and on the next column second dictionary amount and so on)

Comment: ```[{'a',:10,'b':20,'c':5,'d':4},{'a',:0,'b':25,'c':15,'d':40}]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like you to suggest that first, you modify the `list` and then iterate.

Modify using itertools.groupby: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/itertools-groupby-in-python/amp/

Your code should look like

```
final_result = defaultdict(list)
for d in result:
   for k, v in d.items():
      final_result[k].append(v)
```

```
       {%for r in final_result%}
            <div class="jumbotron p-3" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label class=" text-right">{{r['key']}}</label>
                    </div>
                    {%for value in r.values%}
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-left" id="idInput{{ value }}"
                            value="{{ value }}">

                    </div>
                  {%endfor%}
                </div>

            </div>
            {%endfor%}
```

Try this.

Correct if it doesn't work.

Edit 1:
I think what you want to do, can be implemented using below code

```
     {%for r in result[0].keys()%}
            {%for row in result%}
            <div class="jumbotron p-3" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label class=" text-right">{{ r }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-left" id="idInput{{ keyCategory }}"
                            value="{{ row[r] }}">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            {%endfor%}
            {%endfor%}
```

Comment: ```in key_func
    return x['key']
KeyError: 'key'```

Comment: not able to print any key and value, however, able to see all rows exactly same number as keys, any thought ?

Comment: In place of key use whatever key You goy in your dict. example: ```y=[{'a',:10,'b':20,'c':5,'d':4},{'a',:0,'b':25,'c':15,'d':40}] key_func=lambda x: x['a']```

Comment: my system not supporting lambda, can we get normal func. instead lambda

Comment: Yes you can but Python support it by default

Comment: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable, for lembda pylint coming up with error as I need to change in setting

Comment: Learn about lambda : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine after replacing `r.values` to `final_result[r]` in `for-loop`

```
           {%for r in final_result.keys()%}
            <div class="jumbotron p-3" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label class=" text-right">{{r}}</label>
                    </div>
                    {%for value in final_result[r]%}
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-left" id="idInput{{ value }}" value="{{ value }}">

                    </div>
                    {%endfor%}
                </div>

            </div>
            {%endfor%}
```